# Go to respective screen when FlatButton is pressed from AutoCompleteTextField

Tags: search, flutter, dart

With `autocomplete_textfield` package of Flutter, I have made a search bar. When it returns the result as a container, I want to a button in it that'll push to the respected screen of the search result.
But how can I make the button dynamic so that it can go to the screen based on the search result?
For example, if the search result is  `Aishim`, how can I get the button to go to `AishimWidget()` when pressed?

I have added the `FlatButton` to the result container. That goes to `AishimWidget` when pressed.

```
import 'package:autocomplete_textfield/autocomplete_textfield.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smartdoctor/screens/aishim_widget.dart';

class SearchWidget extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    State < StatefulWidget > createState() => _SearchWidgetState();
}

class _SearchWidgetState extends State < SearchWidget > {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
            body: SecondPage(),
        );
    }
}

class ArbitrarySuggestionType {
    String name;
    ArbitrarySuggestionType(this.name);
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    State < StatefulWidget > createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State < SecondPage > {
    List < ArbitrarySuggestionType > suggestions = [
        new ArbitrarySuggestionType("Minamishima"),
        new ArbitrarySuggestionType("Aishim"),
    ];

    GlobalKey key =
    new GlobalKey < AutoCompleteTextFieldState < ArbitrarySuggestionType >> ();

    AutoCompleteTextField < ArbitrarySuggestionType > textField;

    ArbitrarySuggestionType selected;

    _SecondPageState() {
        textField = new AutoCompleteTextField < ArbitrarySuggestionType > (
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Search:", suffixIcon: new Icon(Icons.search)),
            itemSubmitted: (item) => setState(() => selected = item),
            key: key,
            suggestions: suggestions,
            itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) => new Padding(
                child: new ListTile(
                    title: new Text(suggestion.name)),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0)),
            itemSorter: (a, b) => a.stars == b.stars ? 0 : a.stars > b.stars ? -1 : 1,
            itemFilter: (suggestion, input) =>
            suggestion.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(input.toLowerCase()),
        );
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
            body: new Column(children: [
                new Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 64.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                    child: new Card(
                        child: selected != null ?
                        new Column(children: [
                            new Container(
                                child: FlatButton(
                                    onPressed: () => this.onButtonPressed(context))),
                            new ListTile(
                                title: new Text(selected.name)),
                        ]) :
                        new Icon(Icons.home))),
            ]),
        );
    }

    void onButtonPressed(BuildContext context) => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AishimWidget()));
}
```

But it's not dynamic. Can I use any if statement for deciding which screen to go to? Or is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use named-routes https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes 
Map each page with a string

In onButtonPressed, use string

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
```

or in your case might looks like the following, you can pass any string you want like selected.name or suggestion.name

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, suggestion.name);
```

define your route, map each page with a string

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Named Routes Demo',
    // Start the app with the "/" named route. In this case, the app starts
    // on the FirstScreen widget.
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {
      // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
      '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
      // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
      '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
    },
  ));
}
```

full example code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//void main() => runApp(MyApp());
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Named Routes Demo',
    // Start the app with the "/" named route. In this case, the app starts
    // on the FirstScreen widget.
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {
      // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
      '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
      // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
      '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
    },
  ));
}

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Launch screen'),
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigate to the second screen using a named route.
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Screen"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigate back to the first screen by popping the current route
            // off the stack.
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]